# How to changing Bartik's "Show - Main navigaton" mobile menu message?

Tags: theming, navigation

When you install Bartik and minimize your browser to mobile display you can see the caption "*Show - Main navigaton*":

[image]

I want to translate it to Hebrew so I went to `admin/config/regional/translate` and typed the stream to change it but found nothing so I guess it's hardcoded somewhere.

Yet, I searched in page.html.twig and menu-block twig but didn't find this stream. I also didn't find CSS language-construct (as in `content:x;`).

You might know where this stream is located or at least answer with a good way to search it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can translate following strings through the core translation system (`admin/config/regional/translate`):

- `Show &mdash; @configuration.label`
- `Hide &mdash; @configuration.label`

The strings above are defined in `block--system-menu-block.html.twig` at line 17 and 18.

Furthermore you should translate/rename your Main menu name.